# Does adding an old account as IMAP delete the old emails in inbox on Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have removed an email account from my outlook 2007 client which was using the POP3 protocol. The emails have remained in the inbox.

If I add the same address back, but in the IMAP protocol, will those emails be deleted? I cannot lose those emails (I have made a CSV backup and a `.pst` backup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. I added the account back with the IMAP settings and my POP emails were still there after. I could then drag them from my POP inbox to the IMAP inbox with no issues.

Comment: This is not possible, unless you removed the account, but kept the PST still connected, which is what would give you the results you described.

Comment: @LPChip I removed the account using this method: https://www.rogers.com/support/internet/removing-an-email-account-in-microsoft-outlook-2007

Comment: Which confirms what I said.

Comment: @LPChip ah right I just realized what you mean. I kept the PST for all of my folders and also made backups in case anyway

Answer (score 0):

It should not be possible to add the email as it is already in your outlook with the same email address.

You can create a new outlook profile and set it up there, as new email address. It will then not affect your other account either (different profile). You can then import the backup and get it online automatically.

Keep in mind, that your IMAP server may not have enough storage to store all your emails because POP3 normally deletes the mail from the server.

Comment: The email address was removed though